# Lumia Imaging SDK device support

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, lumia-imaging-sdk

How many and what kind of devices does the Lumia SDK support? Does it work fine on non-Lumia phones?
The documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn859596.aspx) says that the library is compatible with all Windows Phone 8 and 8.1 devices.
However, I don't understand the purpose of the devices listed below that. It's kind of ambiguous; is Lumia Imaging SDK supported on the listed devices only or these are the devices on which the SDK was tested?

Simply put, I want to know that if a device (lumia or non-lumia) runs Windows Phone 8.1, will it support the Lumia Imaging SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lumia Imaging SDK is device independent. It will work on all devices with the supported operating system. That means it will work on **all devices** running:

- Windows Phone 8.0
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Windows 8.1 ARM
- Windows 8.1 x86/x64 -- as long as it is a "store"/modern application
- Windows 10 (Windows 10 supports running existing modern applications, however the new type of UWP application is not yet supported by the Lumia Imaging SDK).

This **includes** **non-Lumia Devices** and **non-Surface PCs and tablets**.

I agree that the list on the msdn resource is somewhat confusing. The team is simply enumerating the devices that the SDK has been tested on in case a hardware dependant issue arises - for example in a CameraPreviewImageSource scenario, etc.